# Chart is rendered in Chrome, but not in FF and IE

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, google-chrome

H ey there,

I am developing small web-application based on a lot of PHP and JS code and by chance opened the current index.php in Firefox instead of Chrome (my main dev browser).

I was rather shocked to see that one of my main components, a chart (made with amCharts), was not rendered at all. Strangely enough, the watermark of amCharts is shown...

Now I thought it just a hickup and opened the IE to have another browser for comparison, however, same problem there.

I went back to Chrome and everything is still fine there. This really confused me and made me think that it's a code problem, e.g. an unclosed parenthesis somewhere. So I copy pasted my code into several PHP / JS / HTML validators and none had any hits.

In addition I downloaded the Firebug addon for Firefox hoping to find some kind of error, but there is none to be found.

What I also tried to inserting some "console.log" passages in my code to see whether the code execution stops at some point, no luck either. All log messages are shown with their correct values.

Right now I am kinda at my wits end...

Does anyone have an idea / had a similar problem and knows how to solve this or what causes this or how I could find out what causes this?

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

best regards,
daZza

**EDIT:**

I fine-tuned the console.log commands and basically backtraced every single step. I now have found the problem, but don't know the source of it. Basically my whole view of logic in programming is breaking apart now... One and the same command returns a different result in another browser, what the hell?!

Here's are some code snippets from the problem area:

```
xmlData = xmlHttp.responseXML;
var x=xmlData.getElementsByTagName("row");
xmlRowCount = x.length;

console.log("Rowcount: " + xmlRowCount);



for (i=0;i<xmlRowCount;i++)
{
  do something with every row in the source xml file
}
```

Now the problem is that in Chrome the rowcount is correctly returned as 417. FF returns 0 (I guess IE as well).

How can that be possible? How can a predefined command return different values? I just don't get it...

**Edit2:** To make the browser test complete, I also downloaded and tested Opera. It works fine there, which makes this whole thing even stranger. What is the difference between IE/FF vs. Chrome/Opera?

PS: Here's two screenshots (Chrome and FF) to visualize the problem:

[image: Chrome]
[image: Firefox]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use the below code

```
var x=xmlData.body.all.tags("row");
```

or

```
var x=xmlData.all.tags("row");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, both alternatives throw an error though: TypeError: xmlData.all is undefined and xmlData.body is undefined